# Get Number of Occurrences Based on Date Range and Set Days of Week

Tags: date, coldfusion, iteration

I am trying to calculate the total number of events that would occur based on the following known parameters

1. start date
2. end date
3. Days of the week
4. frequency of weeks (every week, every 2 weeks, etc)

For example, based on the following example data:

1. 05/01/2017
2. 05/31/2017
3. 1,4 (Sunday, Wednesday)
4. Every 2 weeks

I would have to calculate that this event would run four times (5/7, 5/10, 5/21, 5/24)

Below is the skeleton I have set up. I'm fully stumped on how to increment the current day in the loop based on the number of weeks have passed.

```
<cfset local.totalRuns = 0 />

<cfset local.startDate = '2017-05-01' />
<cfset local.endDate = '2017-05-31' />
<cfset local.totalDays = DateDiff("d", local.startDate, local.endDate) />

<cfset local.daysPerWeek = '1,4' />
<cfset local.recurrence = 2 />

<cfset local.currentLoop = 0 />
<cfset local.weeksToCount = local.recurrence * 2 />

<!--- Loop a day at a time --->
<cfloop from="#local.startDate#" to="#local.endDate#" index="local.thisDay" step="#createTimespan(1, 0, 0, 0)#">

    <cfset local.currentDate = local.thisDay />

    <!--- Loop over each allowed day of the current week and determine actual date ---> 
    <cfloop list="#local.daysPerWeek#" index="local.currentDay">


        <!--- if current date does not exceed the end date add increment (this current is incorrect) --->
        <cfif DateDiff("d", local.currentDate, local.endDate) LTE 0>
            <cfset local.totalRuns++ />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfset local.currentLoop++ />
</cfloop>
```

Comment: what values do you get at the end for local.totalRuns and local.currentLoop?

Comment: I'm a huge fan of using date dimension tables for date range checks. I would also think that the trick here would be to fix when the event actually occurs. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, If an even runs on Sundays every 2 weeks, I think this code will return different results if you set the startDate to 5/1 vs 5/8.

Comment: Shawn - You are correct that the 2 weeks is a bit unclear.  1 week would start THIS week, 2 weeks would start the FOLLOWING week, and every 2 after that.  It's the initial one that's a bit off.

Comment: techLove - `local.totalRuns` would be the total occurrences I return to the calling script

Comment: Agreed about calendar tables. They can often simplify this type of task, a lot. *RE: this code will return different results if you set the startDate to 5/1 vs 5/8* Yeah, just my 2¢, but .. not sure I agree with the expected results. I would have expected the event to start on the first Sunday OR Wednesday, i.e. 5/3 rather than 5/7, but that may be an application specific rule.

Comment: @AngrySpartan - (Annoyingly) Once multiple users leave comments, S.O. stops notifying the participants about new comments, unless the comment is tagged with `@` + `username` (Post author is always notified).

Comment: @Leigh, thanks for the fyi

Comment: @AngrySpartan - Welcome. BTW, my answer does not meet the new requirements, ie "*1 week would start THIS week, 2 weeks would start the FOLLOWING week*".  I will need to rework it.

Comment: Sorry, just getting back to this. What should the start be if frequency is 3 or 4 weeks?

Answer (score 1):

This is a formatted comment.  It shows the approach I would take.

```
set the recurrence count to 0

start looping through the list of valid days of the week (1,4) in this case

set the control date to the start date.

do something to set the control date to the earliest 
date that matches the day of the week in this loop.  

if the control date is greater than the end date, break out of the loop.
otherwise

add 1 to the recurrence count

set up a while loop that adds the specified number of weeks 
to the control date, and repeats the check I just described

end looping through the list of valid days of the week (1,4) in this case
```